# Avoid deploy a function to production

Tags: firebase

Assume I use the next simple function for logging

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const logOnWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('{collection}/{document}')
  .onWrite((_, context) => {
    functions.logger.log('onWrite', context);
  });
```

What is the best way to deploy a specific functions only if I use `firebase emulators` ?

I know that I can enable/disable Background Function Triggers but this is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question as you mention both production and emulators. As far as I know, with emulators, you cannot selectively deploy functions as its reading all the functions from your `index.js` and does "hot reload".
For production though, it's an explicit deploy command that you have to issue . For deploying only a subset of functions, there are multiple options as per the Firebase docs here: [Deploy specific functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions)